# How to send a value to php document and redirect to it?

Tags: php, jquery, redirect

I have a button with "orderdetail" class in a html document . I want to get it's id by jquery and send it to the php document then redirect to that php document and then I process that id by POST , but I always get "Notice: Undefined index: id in C:\laragon\www\portal\orderDetail.php on line 9" error.
this is my code :

in html doc:

```
$(document).on('click', '.orderdetail', function () {
    var _id = $(this).attr("id");
    console.log(_id);   //I got the true result here              
    $.post("orderdetail.php", { id: _id }, function (data, status, xhr) {
        window.location.href = "orderdetail.php";
    })
    .... more code not shown
```

in php doc: `echo $_POST['id'];`

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you add the relevant HTML and all the php from orderdetail.php

Comment: The html code generate by another php doc: <a type="button"  name="detail" id="' . $row["orderID"] . '" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm orderdetail">detail</a>

Comment: Look at the page source in the browser then and copy the relevant portion of that where the button is. In the source code does the button have a value assigned by `$row["orderID"]`?

Comment: yes of course. <a type="button" name="detail" id="32" class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm orderdetail">جزئیات</a>

Comment: What's your HTML? What's in your php file? What are you trying to achieve? What framework are you using, or are you just using html and php? Are you rendering any html from PHP or are you trying to pass a value from a php function to your html?

Comment: I want to get order Id and make a query for fetching order detail of that order id and show the detail to user in a table

Comment: Your code first makes an ajax request with the id. When that request is done, you get a success and you redirect to the same page. When you're making that redirect, it will be a _completely different request_. The value you posted in the previous request won't be accessible then. If you want to redirect the browser, don't use Ajax. Either use a normal link and pass the ID in the URL (a GET request) or submit a normal form.

Comment: Read the last part of my comment: _"If you want to redirect the browser, don't use Ajax. Either use a normal link and pass the ID in the URL (a GET request) or submit a normal form. "_ Ajax is for making requests in the background _without_ redirecting the client, which seems to be the opposite from what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [jquery.redirect](https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect) library to send POST data with redirect in the same time.

After importing jQuery, add this file:
https://github.com/mgalante/jquery.redirect/blob/master/jquery.redirect.js

Then use it in JS as so:

```js
$.redirect('file.php', {'First': 'Hello', 'Second': 'World'});
```

In your case:

```js
$.redirect('orderdetail.php', {'id': _id});
```

This POSTs data along with the redirect.